# Trigger error due to  INSERT INTO .. SELECT, error #1442

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I need to do something similar to reputation/awards on stack overflow.

Lets say I want to give out an award when a users rep exceeds 500. (award number 7 for example)

But I only want the award to be given once, so if the rep decreased and then increase again, they wouldn't get two awards.

```
INSERT INTO awards (number, username, date) SELECT 7, username, NOW() FROM users WHERE rep>500;
```

And then have primary key username, number

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE TRIGGER `rewards` BEFORE INSERT ON `awards`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  UPDATE users SET points=points+1 WHERE username=NEW.username AND NEW.number=7;
END
```

but i get this error:

## 1442 - Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply create a trigger on the table awards

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html

Comment: Seconded. Triggers are the way to go.

Comment: wow these seem quite useful. but i've hit a problem, #1442 - Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: it's now at the bottom of the question.

Comment: hm okay, problem is you're doing an INSERT INTO ... SELECT
sorry, no idea how to resolve that one